# I need examples using "Berührungspunkt"

Tags: meaning

Wie kann man

> Berührungspunkt

in einem Satz benutzen? Ich brauche Beispiele.

Comment: Willkommen auf dem Stack Exchange für die deutsche Sprache. Bitte [edit]iere Deine Frage und erläutere, was Du mit den Beispielen zu tun gedenkst oder was Du verstehen möchtest.

Comment: Klingt nach Hausaufgabe.

Comment: Da oben steht so ein Satz.

Answer (score 5):

Leider fehlt der Kontext für Deine Frage. Ein "Berührungspunkt" kommt in der Geometrie vor, z.B. wenn sich zwei Kreise in einem Punkt *berühren*. Sie haben dann nur diesen einen Punkt gemeinsam. Hier:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mathe-lexikon.at](http://www.mathe-lexikon.at/media/advanced_pictures/kreise_5.jpg))</sub>

ist "A" der Berührungspunkt.

Im übertragenen Sinn kann laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beruehrungspunkt#Bedeutung2) die

> geistige, gedankliche Übereinstimmung, Gemeinsamkeit

gemeint sein.

- > Alice und Bob haben keinerlei Berührungspunkte mehr. Sie lassen sich daher scheiden.
- > Eine Frage hat mit den [hier genannten Anforderungen](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) nur wenig Berührungspunkte und wird vielleicht geschlossen.